# Spivak - Calculus, problem 1.19.b

Tags: calculus, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

In Chapter 1, problem 19b:

> Prove the Schwarz inequality by using  $2xy\leq x^2+y^2\tag{1}$ with
> $x=\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}\tag{2}$
> $y=\frac{y_i}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}\tag{3}$

After giving it quite a lot of time, I simply don't understand

a) By what rules am I allowed to substitute $x$ and $y$ with these two rather random values.

b) Where did these two values come from.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality (1) you have shown for all x and y is true if you replace $x$, $y$ with any real numbers.

Then you want to show that for all $x_1$, $x_2$, $y_1$, $y_2$ we have

$x_1.y_1+x_2.y_2\leq \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}.\sqrt{y_1^2+y_2^2}$

you can distinguish two cases:

1. $x_1$ and $x_2$ not both zero and $y_1$ and $y_2$ not both zero
2. ($x_1=0$ and $x_2=0$) or ($y_1=0$ and $y_2=0$)

The hint is for the fisrt case:

$2\frac{x_1.y_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}\sqrt{y_1^2+y_2^2}} \leq \frac{x_1^2}{x_1^2+x_2^2}+\frac{y_1^2}{y_1^2+y_2^2}$ and $2\frac{x_2.y_2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}\sqrt{y_1^2+y_2^2}} \leq \frac{x_2^2}{x_1^2+x_2^2}+\frac{y_2^2}{y_1^2+y_2^2}$

...

Answer (score 0):

$2xy\leq x^2+y^2$ since $0\leq (x-y)^2 =x^2-2xy+y^2$ we obtain that ,

$$\frac{2x_1y_1}{\sqrt{(x_1^2+x_2^2)}\sqrt{(y_1^2+y_2^2)}}\leq \frac{x_1^2}{x_1^2+x_2^2}+\frac{y_1^2}{y_1^2+y_2^2}\tag{1}$$
$$\frac{2x_1y_1}{\sqrt{(x_1^2+x_2^2)}\sqrt{(y_1^2+y_2^2)}}\leq  \frac{x_2^2}{x_1^2+x_2^2}+\frac{y_2^2}{y_1^2+y_2^2}\tag{2}$$

Addition yields

$$\frac{2(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}\sqrt{y_1^2+y_2^2}}\leq 2$$

Answer (score 0):

Spivak's answers often assume a level of comfort with basic math skills. So, for those , like me, who are honing up on this, my attempt.

We are required to show

> ${x}_{1}{y}_{1} + {x}_{2}{y}_{2} \le \sqrt{{x}_{1}^{2} + {x}_{2}^{2}}\sqrt{{y}_{1}^{2} + {y}_{2}^{2}}$

using

> $2xy \le {x}^{2} + {y}^{2}$  with $x = \frac{x_i}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}}$ and $y = \frac{y_i}{\sqrt{y_1^2 + y_2^2}}$

Let $ a = x_1^2 + x_2^2$ and $ b = y_1^2 + y_2^2$

First for $i = 1$
$$\begin {align}  2\left[ \frac{{x}_{1}}{\sqrt{a}} \cdot \frac{{y}_{1}}{\sqrt{b}} \right] &\le \left[ \frac{{x}_{1}}{\sqrt{a}}\right]^2 + \left[ \frac{{y}_{1}}{\sqrt{b}}\right]^2 \\ 2\left[ \frac{{x}_{1}{y}_{1} }{\sqrt{ab}}  \right] &\le  \frac{{x}_{1}^{2}}{a} +  \frac{{y}_{1}^{2}}{b}\\ &= \frac{b({x}_{1}^{2}) +a({y}_{1}^{2})}{ab} \end{align}$$

For $i = 2 $
$$2\left[ \frac{{x}_{2}{y}_{2} }{\sqrt{ab}}  \right] \le  \frac{b({x}_{2}^{2}) +a({y}_{2}^{2})}{ab}$$

Addition yields:

$$\begin{align}2\left[ \frac{{x}_{1}{y}_{1}+{x}_{2}{y}_{2} }{\sqrt{ab}}  \right] &\le  \frac{b({x}_{1}^{2}) +a({y}_{1}^{2})+b({x}_{2}^{2}) +a({y}_{2}^{2})}{ab} \\  &\le  \frac{b({x}_{1}^{2} + {x}_{2}^{2}) +a({y}_{1}^{2} + {y}_{2}^{2}) }{ab}\\ &=  \frac{ba +ab }{ab}\\ &= \frac{2ab}{ab} \\ &= 2 \end{align}$$

yielding

$${x}_{1}{y}_{1}+{x}_{2}{y}_{2}  \le  \sqrt{ab}= \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b} = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}\sqrt{y_1^2 + y_2^2} $$